# Как на флексах прижать первую строку к левому краю, вторую к правому?

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть такой блок, сверстанный на флоатах.

```css
.bonuses_block {
    display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bonuses_block:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

.bonuses_block .bonus_item {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.bonuses_block .bonus_item:first-child {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  background: #ffb800;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10rem 0 rgba(255,184,1,0.6);
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
}

.bonuses_block .bonus_item:last-child {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
  background: #ff4a00;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10rem 0 rgba(255,74,0,0.6);
    transform: rotate(6.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bonuses_block">
    <div class="bonus_item">Текст бонуса 1</div>
    <div class="bonus_item">Текст бонуса 2</div>
</div>
```

Как этот блок сверстать на флексах, чтобы был такой же эффект? Чтобы верхняя строка прижималась к левому краю, нижняя - к правому.

Пытаюсь сделать так, но не пойму, как нижнюю строку прижать к правому краю.

```css
.bonuses_block {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .bonuses_block .bonus_item {
        padding: 6px 10px;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .bonuses_block .bonus_item:first-child {
      background: #ffb800;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10rem 0 rgba(255,184,1,0.6);
        transform: rotate(-7deg);
    }

    .bonuses_block .bonus_item:last-child {
      background: #ff4a00;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10rem 0 rgba(255,74,0,0.6);
        transform: rotate(6.5deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="bonuses_block">
    <div class="bonus_item">Текст бонуса 1</div>
    <div class="bonus_item">Текст бонуса 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как этот блок сверстать на флексах, чтобы был такой же эффект? Чтобы верхняя строка прижималась к левому краю, нижняя - к правому.

Предложу такой вариант для решения проблемы...

```css
.bonuses_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* добавил */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-Items: flex-start;
}

.bonuses_block .bonus_item {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.bonuses_block .bonus_item:first-child {
  background: #ffb800;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10rem 0 rgba(255, 184, 1, 0.6);
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}

.bonuses_block .bonus_item:last-child {
  background: #ff4a00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10rem 0 rgba(255, 74, 0, 0.6);
  transform: rotate(6.5deg);
  /* добавил */
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="bonuses_block">
  <div class="bonus_item">Текст бонуса 1</div>
  <div class="bonus_item">Текст бонуса 2</div>
</div>
```